# How to unload package with all dependences that are not explicitly loaded / are not used by other explicitly loaded packages?

Tags: r, package

I want to unload package and all its dependancies. But I do not want to unload packages that I have previously loaded with `library()` or packages that are dependencies of packages that I loaded with `library()`. How can I do it?

Comment: Maybe like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979917/how-to-unload-a-package-without-restarting-r

Comment: @M.Viking I have already looked at it but did not found "But I do not want to unload packages that I have previously loaded with `library()` or packages that are dependencies of packages that I loaded with `library()`."

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, [you can't automatically differentiate between packages that are `Depends` dependencies of other attached packages and the ones you load with `library`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56589800/can-r-differentiate-between-a-manually-loaded-library-and-a-dependency).

EDIT: I've updated my answer to the question linked above,
showing a possible alternative to track explicit usages of `library`.
It would be possible to use it to compute `attached` in the code below instead of using `search`.

Here's one possibility I found using the `remotes` package:

```
transitive_deps <- function(package, acc = character()) {
    direct_deps <- remotes::local_package_deps(system.file(package = package))
    filtered_deps <- setdiff(direct_deps, acc)

    if (length(filtered_deps) == 0L) {
        package
    }
    else {
        acc <- union(acc, filtered_deps)
        for (dep in filtered_deps) { acc <- union(acc, transitive_deps(dep, acc)) }
        union(package, acc)
    }
}

unload_deep <- function(package) {
    # find all transitive dependencies of the package
    deps <- transitive_deps(package) # alternatively: remotes::package_deps(package)$package
    # do not unload base packages
    deps <- setdiff(deps, installed.packages(priority = "base")[, "Package"])
    # do not unload packages explicitly attached with library()
    attached <- search()
    deps <- setdiff(deps, substring(attached, unlist(gregexpr(":", attached)) + 1L)) # remove "package:" prefix
    # first unload provided package
    tryCatch(unloadNamespace(package), error = function(...) {
        package <- paste0("package:", package)
        if (package %in% search()) {
            # at least try to detach it if some other package imports it
            detach(package, character.only = TRUE)
        }
    })

    deps <- setdiff(deps, package)
    # try to unload remaining
    while (length(deps) > 0L) {
        unloaded_one <- FALSE
        for (dep in deps) {
            flag <- try(unloadNamespace(dep), silent = TRUE)
            if (!inherits(flag, "try-error")) {
                unloaded_one <- TRUE
                break
            }
        }

        if (unloaded_one) {
            deps <- setdiff(deps, dep)
        }
        else {
            # could not unload any, must be used by other unrelated packages
            break
        }
    }
    # return
    invisible()
}
```

You need to pass a character in `package`.
Also, as mentioned in the code comments,
you can use `remotes::package_deps(package)$package` instead of the `transitive_deps` helper.
I think the former already filters `base` packages,
but I believe it checks online each time you use it.

The `transitive_deps` helper is far from perfect,
it just tries to find direct dependencies
(which is what `remotes::local_package_deps` returns)
recursively,
hopefully avoiding some repetition by using `acc` to accumulate already seen packages.

The order in which packages are unloaded is important,
because you cannot unload a package that is imported by another currently loaded package.
Unfortunately the order in `deps` is not always perfect for that,
that's why there's a `try` in the loop,
to skip problematic packages until all dependent packages have been unloaded.